# Unable to change private variable's content

Tags: c++, class, variables, object, private

main.cpp :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include "Players.h"
using namespace std;

int main ()
{
    cout << "**** Welcome to Leviathan's first TicTacToe Game! ****\n\n";
    Players getNamesobject;
    Players printNamesobject;
    getNamesobject.getPlayersNames();
    printNamesobject.printPlayersNames();

}
```

Players.h:

```
#ifndef PLAYERS_H
#define PLAYERS_H


class Players
{
    public:
        void getPlayersNames();
        void printPlayersNames();
    private:
        std::string _player1Name;
        std::string _player2Name;
};

#endif // PLAYERS_H
```

Players.cpp :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include "Players.h"
using namespace std;

void Players::getPlayersNames()
{
    string p1,p2;
    cout << "Enter player 1 name : ";
    cin >> p1;
    cout << "\nEnter player 2 name : ";
    cin >> p2;
    _player1Name = p1;
    _player2Name = p2;
}

void Players::printPlayersNames()
{
    cout << "Alright " << _player1Name << " and " << _player2Name <<", the game has begun!\n\n";
}
```

When i run this, and enter two names, the _player1Name and _player2Name variables don't get changed. I've tried setting them a string manually and they get printed normally. Can anyone explain what's wrong here? It seems like getPlayerNames function can't change the private variables?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's because you have *two different objects*!

One that you set the member variables in (through the `getPlayersNames` function), and another unrelated object you use to print a different set of variables.

You should have a single object, and call `getPlayersNames` and `printPlayersNames` on that single object. Like

```
Players playersObject;
playersObject.getPlayersNames();
playersObject.printPlayersNames();
```

---

Each instance of the `Players` object you create will have its own set of member variables that are tied to that single object, member variables are not shared between objects (unless you make them `static`).

Comment: Thank you, it worked!

One more question, why does making the variables static make them able  to be used by other objects? I thought that static just declares the variable only once.

Comment: @Leviathan A `static` member variable exists and is ***shared*** between all instances of a class.

Comment: @Leviathan please set this as the answer...if not Joachim will not be credited for it.

Comment: Sorry, i'm new to stack overflow, i'll mark it as answered now.